# angular2 directive `Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` with outputs metadata

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Regarding Angular2 directive, I wanted to use `outputs` instead of using `@Output` because I have many custom events and wanted to keep DRY.

However, I am having `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`, and I don't know why it's happening.

http://plnkr.co/edit/SFL9fo?p=preview

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
  outputs: ['myEvent']
}) 
export class MyDirective {
  constructor() {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>> this.myEvent', this.myEvent);
  }
}
```

[image]

And this is app component that uses this directive

[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to initialize the output:

```
import { Directive } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]',
  outputs: ['myEvent']
}) 
export class MyDirective {
  myEvent:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); // <-----

  constructor() {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>> this.myEvent', this.myEvent);
  }
}
```

You could also use the `@HostListener` decorator:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[my-directive]'
}) 
export class MyDirective {
  @HostListener('myEvent')
  myEvent:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(); // <-----

  constructor() {
    console.log('>>>>>>>>> this.myEvent', this.myEvent);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! In fact, you must initialize it by yourself ;-)

Comment: This is still applicable in Angular 5.x