# Angular Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a dynamic menu using a json response from server but I am getting this error:

> MenuComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
>       at MatMenuTrigger.push../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/menu.es5.js.MatMenuTrigger.ngAfterContentInit

and when I click the buttons it says this:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEmbeddedView' of undefined
>       at ViewContainerRef_.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ViewContainerRef_.createEmbeddedView

I am guessing that buttons can't created because json response is not ready but I don't know how to fix it.

**Component.ts**

```
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  branchList: Branches = new Branches(); //read somewhere that I need to initialize, not sure

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get('http://demo8635782.mockable.io/branches').subscribe((data: any) => {
      if (data === null) {
        console.log('api request returns empty!');
      }
      this.branchList = data;
    });
  }

  constructor(private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver, private http: HttpClient) {
  }
}
```

**Template.html**

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="branchesMenu">Branches</button>
<mat-menu #branchesMenu="matMenu">
  <div *ngFor="let branch of branchList?.branches">
    <button mat-menu-item [matMenuTriggerFor]="branch?.name">{{branch.name}}</button>
  </div>
</mat-menu>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-clgkte)

Comment: the line you're unsure about.. what about changing from `branchList: Branches = new Branches();` to `branchList: Branches;` ? does it change the error?  ... also I've never seen a type declared for ngOnInit- there is no need

Comment: nope, it doesn't change anything, I saw it from here:  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37765519/angular2-directive-cannot-read-property-subscribe-of-undefined-with-outputs)

Comment: Please create an [mcve], I recommend https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: @Igor I added the example

Comment: Interface of returned data must not be similar to interface of branchList, and that is creating error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sfaq7i)
I use the correct version of material and angular updating the dependencies, use the observable in the template wrapping the button in a ngIf, also deleted the matMenuTriggerFor of the mat-menu-item and import the BrowserAnimationsModule in the app.module.

Edit for adding subMenu, for it you must create the submenu inside the ngFor iteration.

Comment: thanks but I need matMenuTriggerFor  because I will just create a menu from that json response.

Comment: Edit the response adding subMenu

Answer (score 3):

You're overcomplicating it.  It's just a matter of the return type of HttpClient.get.  Apparently it's not returning an Observable, and you'll need to read the docs for the library to see why.

You could also simplify the code a great deal:

```
export class AppComponent  {
  readonly branches = this.http
    .get('https://demo8635782.mockable.io/branches')
    .pipe(
    map((data) => data as Branches),
    map(({branches}) =>branches),
    shareReplay(),
  );    
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
}


<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="branchesMenu">Branches</button>
<mat-menu #branchesMenu="matMenu">
 <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let branch of (branches | async)">{{branch.name}}</button>
</mat-menu>
```

**EDIT:** nope, totally wrong.  As Daniel Caldera pointed out below, the actual problem was the matMenuTriggerFor of the mat-menu-item.

Other problems:

1. You need to import BrowserAnimationsModule
2. You need to import the operators (map, shareReplay)
3. You need to include the theme in CSS
4. You shouldn't de-reference an async, as I originally suggested

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ukzixo) is my working version.

Comment: I tried your code but it gives me error about map: Function implementation missing. even though I added "target": "es6", and     "lib": [ "es6", "es2017", "es2015", "dom", "esnext" ] to tsconfig.I am new to Typescript and Angular so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Cagurtay -- does that mean you figured out your `get()` problem?  I was missing a parenthesis after the word `pipe` (fixed now), maybe that was doing it.

Comment: nope, it give errors for map and replay. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gmdpkq)

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, it is working but now I need to find a way to parse that JSON and create nested menu from it, that's why I was using matMenuTriggerFor

Comment: Start from an example of submenus first.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. Made a login to refresh my token.
The backend expects token so the request has to be made with a valid token.

*Make sure you've valid token in your request.*

*Review your backend.*